# Batch download a series of files and add prefix to them

Tags: bash, download, batch-jobs

So I have a list of downloadable links with a specific order, but the filenames are jumbled up

```
example.com/ddk.zip
example.com/453.zip
example.com/hth.zip
```

So I want to automatically prefix them as I download them, based on the order of the list of links, so they'd look like this:

```
001_ddk.zip
002_453.zip
003_hth.zip
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Bash?

Comment: What are you stuck on?  `wget` downloads a file. Remember to prefix the link with `http://` or `https://`. Once downloaded you can rename the file with `mv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a piece of script

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

prefix=1

while read link; do
  filename="$(printf "%03d" $prefix)_${link##*/}"
  echo "wget $link -O $filename"
  prefix=$((prefix+1))
done < <(cat /tmp/list)
```

obviously remove the the `echo` on the wget command to execute it for real

**result:**

```
$ bash script.sh
wget example.com/ddk.zip -O 001_ddk.zip
wget example.com/453.zip -O 002_453.zip
wget example.com/hth.zip -O 003_hth.zip
wget example.com/ddhth.zip -O 004_ddhth.zip
wget example.com/hggth.zip -O 005_hggth.zip
wget example.com/jhkhth.zip -O 006_jhkhth.zip
```

And yep, you'll need to edit your link list and add http:// or https:// before

Comment: What if your links are already in "http://http://example.com/file.zip" format? With an arbitrary number of slashes, how would you trim it down to just the filename?

Comment: my bad, I edited my script to keep only the text after the last slash (## instead of #)